# Bootstrap X-Editables checklist source issue (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable, checklistbox

i am new here and new to .NET.
I have been tinkering with Bootstrap X-Editables and with most of its input types, its been wonderful until i came across the checklist input.
I am currently using Ajax to post the checked values to a web services (ASMX in C#).
The only problem is, although it is posting an array, I am having nightmares trying to capture it on the ASMX web method.
Here is my X-Editable code:

```
//make status editable
          $('#OfferingTypeAllocation').editable({
            type: 'select',
            title: 'Select status',
            placement: 'right',
            value: 2,
            source: [
              {value: 1, text: 'status 1'},
              {value: 2, text: 'status 2'},
              {value: 3, text: 'status 3'}
            ],
                
            // uncomment these lines to send data to the server
            pk: 1,
            url: '/Services/Passport.asmx/ProcessArray'
          });
```

and the payload looks like this:

```
name: OfferingTypeAllocation
value[]: 1
value[]: 2
value[]: 3
pk: 1
PassportId: 1
```

The following is a very basic method i wrote to capture the array:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void ProcessArray(int[] values)
        {
            // Process the array here
            foreach (int value in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
```

This would show an error of NullReference. I tried many different ways to capture this array but i simply cannot get anything to work.

I would appreciate some advice from you good folks.

Comment: Just to add, I have included all the other form values in the web method and still had the same issue. If i remove int[] value then the web method works fine so the array is incorrectly formatted i think but the format cannot be changed on X-Editables